# How do you connect to an external schema/table on Redshift Spectrum through AWS Quicksight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-quicksight, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have spun up a Redshift cluster and added my S3 external schema by running

```
CREATE EXTERNAL SCHEMA s3 FROM DATA CATALOG
DATABASE '<aws_glue_db>'
IAM_ROLE '<redshift_s3_glue_iam_role_arn>';
```

to access the AWS Glue Data Catalog. Everything is fine on Redshift, I can query data and all is well. On Quicksight, however, the table is recognized but is empty.

Do i have to move the data *into* Redshift? If so, would the only reason I should be using Redshift be to process Parquet files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just wrote a custom SQL expression to select the relevant fields

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select external tables from redshift, I think the role you're using is missing access to s3

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-cross-account-glue-s3/

Comment: On Redshift i can see the external table and query it, but on Quicksight it is shown as empty

Comment: https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-quicksight-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/enabling-access-redshift.md.  you need to policies attached to the role : Add the IAM policies AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess and AmazonAthenaFullAccess to the IAM role.

Comment: 1. What IAM Role are you referring to? The one for Redshift?
2. Why Athena? Is Spectrum and Glue not enough?